# Can No Longer Access ArcadeDB-Studio Upon Restarting Its Docker Container

Tags: dockerfile, graph-databases, restart, docker-container, arcadedb

## What are the details of your problem?

I can't get to my [ArcadeDB-Studio](https://docs.arcadedb.com/#Studio) instance after restarting [its Docker-container](https://hub.docker.com/r/arcadedata/arcadedb).
Currently, I'm working on researching-and-testing ArcadeDB and I shutdown the PC each day.
Problem is when I return, Docker restarts and I restart my ArcadeDB-container and I can no longer get to its Studio.

How do I fix my ArcadeDB-Docker-instance to work on restart?

```
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

## What did you try and what were you expecting?

I tried stopping-and-starting, stopping-and-restarting, and just restarting with the Docker-UI but the same problem of being unable to access the ArcadeDB-Studio.
I tried running a [local ArcadeDB-release](https://github.com/ArcadeData/arcadedb/releases) [`server.bat`](https://github.com/ArcadeData/arcadedb/blob/466eaf9f1616ee40c423cea93d4b0d529f2e7582/package/src/main/scripts/server.bat#L58) that I'm testing / learning with, too. That worked fine on restarting. With this error message, am I just looking at a false-flag / red-herring?

I don't understand if I just messed up with Docker, ArcadeDB, or I need to edit the `dockerfile` that gets used instead.
I don't know ArcadeDB nor Docker well enough to make an educated judgment or insight on this.
Is there anybody that is well-versed and/or familiar with these two together?

```js
2023-05-31 07:34:46  █████╗ ██████╗  ██████╗ █████╗ ██████╗ ███████╗██████╗ ██████╗
2023-05-31 07:34:46 ██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝██╔══██╗██╔══██╗
2023-05-31 07:34:46 ███████║██████╔╝██║     ███████║██║  ██║█████╗  ██║  ██║██████╔╝
2023-05-31 07:34:46 ██╔══██║██╔══██╗██║     ██╔══██║██║  ██║██╔══╝  ██║  ██║██╔══██╗
2023-05-31 07:34:46 ██║  ██║██║  ██║╚██████╗██║  ██║██████╔╝███████╗██████╔╝██████╔╝
2023-05-31 07:34:46 ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═╝ ╚═════╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═════╝ ╚══════╝╚═════╝ ╚═════╝
2023-05-31 07:34:46 PLAY WITH DATA                                    arcadedb.com
2023-05-31 07:34:46 removing old pid file /home/arcadedb/bin/arcadedb.pid
2023-05-31 07:34:46 
2023-05-31 07:34:46 2023-05-31 12:34:46.796 INFO  [ArcadeDBServer] <ArcadeDB_0> ArcadeDB Server v23.3.1-SNAPSHOT (build 0393db01efcce6d393482991ff18b330970081ef/1678969633791/main) is starting up...
2023-05-31 07:34:46 2023-05-31 12:34:46.807 INFO  [ArcadeDBServer] <ArcadeDB_0> Running on Linux 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 - OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.18+10
2023-05-31 07:34:46 2023-05-31 12:34:46.807 INFO  [ArcadeDBServer] <ArcadeDB_0> Starting ArcadeDB Server in development mode with plugins [Redis, MongoDB, Postgres, GremlinServer] ...
2023-05-31 07:34:47 2023-05-31 12:34:46.819 INFO  [ArcadeDBServer] <ArcadeDB_0> - JMX Metrics Started...
2023-05-31 07:34:48 2023-05-31 12:34:47.632 INFO  [SourceDiscovery] <ArcadeDB_0> Analyzing url: https://github.com/ArcadeData/arcadedb-datasets/raw/main/orientdb/OpenBeer.gz...
2023-05-31 07:34:48 2023-05-31 12:34:48.312 INFO  [SourceDiscovery] <ArcadeDB_0> Recognized format OrientDB (parsingLimitBytes=9.54MB parsingLimitEntries=0)
2023-05-31 07:34:49 Importing OrientDB database from stream to './databases/Imported'
2023-05-31 07:34:49 Creation of the schema: types, properties and indexes
2023-05-31 07:34:49 - Created index UNIQUE on Beer[id]
2023-05-31 07:34:49 - Created index UNIQUE on Brewery[id]
2023-05-31 07:34:49 - Created index UNIQUE on Style[id]
2023-05-31 07:34:49 - Created index UNIQUE on Category[id]
2023-05-31 07:34:49 Creation of records started: creating vertices and documents records (edges on the next phase)
2023-05-31 07:34:49 2023-05-31 12:34:48.312 INFO  [Importer] <ArcadeDB_0> Checking schema...Exception in thread "main" com.arcadedb.exception.CommandExecutionException: Error on importing database
2023-05-31 07:34:49 - Status update: parsed 9,997 (9,997/sec) - 0 documents (0/sec) - 5,417 vertices (5,417/sec) - 0 edges (0/sec) - 0 skipped edges - 0 linked edges (0/sec - 0%)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.query.sql.parser.ImportDatabaseStatement.executeSimple(ImportDatabaseStatement.java:69)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.query.sql.executor.SingleOpExecutionPlan.executeInternal(SingleOpExecutionPlan.java:91)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.query.sql.parser.SimpleExecStatement.execute(SimpleExecStatement.java:52)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.query.sql.parser.Statement.execute(Statement.java:77)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.query.sql.parser.Statement.execute(Statement.java:61)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.query.sql.SQLQueryEngine.command(SQLQueryEngine.java:104)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.database.EmbeddedDatabase.command(EmbeddedDatabase.java:1257)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.server.ServerDatabase.command(ServerDatabase.java:416)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.server.ArcadeDBServer.loadDefaultDatabases(ArcadeDBServer.java:495)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.server.ArcadeDBServer.start(ArcadeDBServer.java:139)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.server.ArcadeDBServer.main(ArcadeDBServer.java:92)
2023-05-31 07:34:49 Caused by: com.arcadedb.integration.importer.ImportException: Error on parsing source 'https://github.com/ArcadeData/arcadedb-datasets/raw/main/orientdb/OpenBeer.gz (compressed=true size=1085781)'
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.integration.importer.Importer.load(Importer.java:63)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.query.sql.parser.ImportDatabaseStatement.executeSimple(ImportDatabaseStatement.java:61)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     ... 10 more
2023-05-31 07:34:49 Caused by: com.arcadedb.exception.DuplicatedKeyException: Duplicated key [1] found on index 'Category[id]' already assigned to record #73:0
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.database.TransactionIndexContext.checkUniqueIndexKeys(TransactionIndexContext.java:344)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.database.TransactionIndexContext.checkUniqueIndexKeys(TransactionIndexContext.java:379)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.database.TransactionIndexContext.commit(TransactionIndexContext.java:161)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.database.TransactionContext.commit1stPhase(TransactionContext.java:487)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.database.TransactionContext.commit(TransactionContext.java:114)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.database.EmbeddedDatabase.lambda$commit$2(EmbeddedDatabase.java:356)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.database.EmbeddedDatabase.executeInReadLock(EmbeddedDatabase.java:1326)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.database.EmbeddedDatabase.commit(EmbeddedDatabase.java:351)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.integration.importer.OrientDBImporter.parseRecords(OrientDBImporter.java:341)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.integration.importer.OrientDBImporter.parseInputFile(OrientDBImporter.java:287)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.integration.importer.OrientDBImporter.run(OrientDBImporter.java:176)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.integration.importer.format.OrientDBImporterFormat.load(OrientDBImporterFormat.java:48)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.integration.importer.Importer.loadFromSource(Importer.java:93)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     at com.arcadedb.integration.importer.Importer.load(Importer.java:54)
2023-05-31 07:34:49     ... 15 more
```

```js
docker run -d --name arcadeDb -p 2424:2424 -p 2480:2480 -p 8182:8182 
       --env JAVA_OPTS="-Darcadedb.server.rootPassword=playwithdata 
          -Darcadedb.server.defaultDatabases=Imported[root]{import:https://github.com/ArcadeData/arcadedb-datasets/raw/main/orientdb/OpenBeer.gz} 
          -Darcadedb.server.plugins=GremlinServer:com.arcadedb.server.gremlin.GremlinServerPlugin " 
          arcadedata/arcadedb:latest
```